# Clicking a link within a dropdown menu using C# WebDriver

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I've used every possible combination/variation I could think of involving Actions.MouseMove and IMouse (with elements and coordinates), Actions.Click, Actions.DoubleClick, IWebElement.Click, and Thread.Sleep.

No matter what I do, it always either mouses out of the dropdown menu before trying to click (thus raising an exception when trying to click the element) or seemingly successfully clicks the link but then fails to cause the browser (IE 9) to follow the link.

However, I've gotten to click the link and proceed to the following page as expected when running in Debug mode (haven't figured out why).

Any ideas?

(I'd post some code here, but I've scrapped and rewritten and tweaked code for this problem so many times with essentially identical results that I'm not sure how useful it'd be; at this point, I'm basically fishing for completely novel approaches for me to test out and report back on, rather than minor tweaks to any particular revision of my code.)

---

Edit: By request: the HTML code:

```
<div id="sxmenu_main">
        <ul>
                <li>
                    <span>Header Item 1</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/linka" target="_self">Link A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/linkb" target="_self">Link B</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Header Item 2</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/linka" target="_self">Link A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/linkb" target="_self">Link B</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML of the dropdown menu? Does it rely on any external sources? (i.e any JS?)

Comment: Just posted the code. We're using ASP.NET, but it doesn't look like these dropdown menus are doing anything interesting that should be causing problems with Selenium. Each menu drops down to reveal the links under the appropriate <ul> when a user mouses over the parent <li>.